# How to go to a specific tab in a Sliding Tab Layout from another activity

Tags: java, android, tabs

In my Main Activity I have a Sliding Tab Layout with three tabs. Clicking on a button in the first tab leads to a series of activities. I want the following: Clicking on a button in the last activity of the series should take the user to the second tab of my Main Activity (the Sliding Tab Layout).

Addendum: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539664/how-to-go-to-a-specific-tab-from-a-different-class) is a similar question. Having looked at it, where do I place `onResume` and it's function `setCurrentTab`? Do I place it in MainActivity, the Adapter, or the Page Fragments? What would the code for `onResume` and it's function `setCurrentTab` look like?

Sliding Tab Layout

[image]

Sliding Tab Strip

[image]

MainActivity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MainFragmentPageAdapterForTabs(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                MainActivity.this));

        // Give the SlidingTabLayout the ViewPager
        SlidingTabLayout slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        // Center the tabs in the layout
        slidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
        slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);



    }

    public void takeSurveyButtonAction(View view){
        Intent intentSurvey = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SurveyActivity1.class);
        startActivity(intentSurvey);
    }
}
```

Fragment Adapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class MainFragmentPageAdapterForTabs extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Take Survey", "Results", "Credits"};
    private Context context;

    public MainFragmentPageAdapterForTabs(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return MainPageFragmentForTabs.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
}
```

Page Fragments:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

// In this case, the fragment displays simple text based on the page
public class MainPageFragmentForTabs extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

    private int mPage;

    public static MainPageFragmentForTabs newInstance(int page) {

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
        MainPageFragmentForTabs fragment = new MainPageFragmentForTabs();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view = null;

        if(mPage==1){
            View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page_recycler_view, container, false);
            FragmentActivity a = getActivity();

            //recycler
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view1.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            //layout manager
            LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(a);
            manager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
            //recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

            MainAdapterCV1 ca = new MainAdapterCV1();
            recyclerView.setAdapter(ca);

            view=view1;

        }

        if(mPage==2){

            View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page_recycler_view, container, false);
            FragmentActivity a = getActivity();

            //recycler
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view2.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            //layout manager
            LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(a);
            manager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
            //recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

            ResultsMainAdapterCV2 ca = new ResultsMainAdapterCV2();
            recyclerView.setAdapter(ca);

            view=view2;

        }

        if(mPage==3){

            View view3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page_recycler_view, container, false);
            FragmentActivity a = getActivity();

            //recycler
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view3.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            //layout manager
            LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(a);
            manager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
            //recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

            CreditsMainAdapterCV3 ca = new CreditsMainAdapterCV3();
            recyclerView.setAdapter(ca);

            view=view3;

        }

        return view;
    }

}
```

The Activity that should lead to the second tab in MainActivity.class (by clicking on submitButton):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SurveyActivity13 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RadioGroup radioGroup;
    private RadioButton radioButton;
    private Button submitButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_survey_activity13);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.opt1:
                if (checked)
                    // Pirates are the best
                    break;
            case R.id.opt2:
                if (checked)
                    // Ninjas rule
                    break;
        }
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
        submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.takeSurveyButton);

        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1){
                    //happens if no radio buttons are checked
                    Toast.makeText(
                            SurveyActivity13.this,
                            "You have not selected an option",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                else{
                    //happens if one of the radio buttons is checked

                    // get selected radio button from radioGroup
                    int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                    // find the radio button by returned id
                    radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

                    //save selection
                    String response = radioButton.getText().toString();

                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(
                            "MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("sex", response);
                    editor.apply();

                    //I want this to go to the second tab in MainActivity.class
                    Intent intentSurvey = new Intent(SurveyActivity13.this, MainActivity.class);  
                    startActivity(intentSurvey);

                }

            }

        });

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_survey_activity13, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using:

```
int page = 1;
viewPager.setCurrentItem(page);
```

EDIT:
Passing the page index as an intent from your last Activity to your initial one

```
public void submitButton(View view){
    Intent intentSurvey = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intentSurvey.putExtra(ARG_PAGE, page);
    startActivity(intentSurvey);
}
```

Getting the argument in the main Activity:

```
    int defaultValue = 0;
    int page = getIntent().getIntExtra(ARG_PAGE, defaultValue);
    viewpager.setCurrentItem(page);
```

Comment: I add this to the last activity in the series after intentSurvey, but before startActivity?

Comment: Add the page you want to choose as an extra in the Intent that the SurveyActivity13 Activity reads.

Comment: Can you give me some dummy code for this? I want to put what you just said together with .setCurrentItem()

Comment: Please accept my "suggested edit" so I can accept your answer. It works in my app.

Comment: Couldn't change the answer directly from the suggestion so I just changed it :p

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your activity.

this will help you to get an idea.
This will show the tab you want when first open the activity.

```
 @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(Your fragment name);

    }
```