# How to open a specific tabbed activity on button click?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity which contains 2 buttons - Login and Sign up. Both of these has an activity linked (Fragment based Tabbed activity) which contains the Login/Signup form.

Now I'm unable to navigate to the particular tab when clicked on a button. ie, If signup button is clicked, it should open Signup fragment based tab and If login button is clicked, it should open login fragment based tab.

How do I achieve this?

Below are my codes for the respective actions.

**Home Activity.java -**

```
public class HomeActivity  extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        findViewById(R.id.signup_btn).setOnClickListener(listener_signup_btn);
        findViewById(R.id.signin_btn).setOnClickListener(listener_signin_btn);
    }

    View.OnClickListener listener_signup_btn = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, SignupActivity.class);
            //startActivity(intent);
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener listener_signin_btn = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, HomeTaberActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
}
```

**HomeTaberActivity.java -**

```
public class HomeTaberActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

    private TabLayout hometabLayout;

    private ViewPager homeviewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hometaber);

        hometabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.hometabLayout);

        hometabLayout.addTab(hometabLayout.newTab().setText("Sign In"));
        hometabLayout.addTab(hometabLayout.newTab().setText("Sign Up"));
        hometabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        homeviewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.homepager);

        HomePager adapter = new HomePager(getSupportFragmentManager(), hometabLayout.getTabCount());

        adapter.Initialise(new LoginActivity(),new SignupActivity());
        adapter.addstring("Sign In"); adapter.addstring("Sign Up");
        homeviewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        hometabLayout.setupWithViewPager(homeviewPager);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        homeviewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30825009/3395198

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Add one value with intent. i.e. for login 1 and signup 2. and check in activity if value is 1 then viewpager current item 0 and if 2 then viewpager current item 1.**

**Home Activity.java** :

```
public class HomeActivity  extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        findViewById(R.id.signup_btn).setOnClickListener(listener_signup_btn);
        findViewById(R.id.signin_btn).setOnClickListener(listener_signin_btn);
    }

    View.OnClickListener listener_signup_btn = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, HomeTaberActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("value", 1);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener listener_signin_btn = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, HomeTaberActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("value", 2);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
}
```

**HomeTaberActivity.java** :

```
public class HomeTaberActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

    private TabLayout hometabLayout;

    private ViewPager homeviewPager;
    int value;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hometaber);

        hometabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.hometabLayout);

        hometabLayout.addTab(hometabLayout.newTab().setText("Sign In"));
        hometabLayout.addTab(hometabLayout.newTab().setText("Sign Up"));
        hometabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        homeviewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.homepager);

        HomePager adapter = new HomePager(getSupportFragmentManager(), hometabLayout.getTabCount());

        adapter.Initialise(new LoginActivity(),new SignupActivity());
        adapter.addstring("Sign In"); adapter.addstring("Sign Up");
        homeviewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        hometabLayout.setupWithViewPager(homeviewPager);

           final Intent intent = new Intent(getIntent());
           value = intent.getIntExtra("value", -1);

           if(value == 1) {
                  viewpager.setCurrentItem(0);
              } else {
                  viewpager.setCurrentItem(1);
              }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        homeviewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Followed this method. It crashes the app and shows an error that SignupActivity is not declared in AndroidManifest. But in AndroidManifest file, it doesn't show any way to declare that

Comment: that's your another problem. may be you forget to declare any activity in manifest. check it once. this error is not related to this

Comment: i have just added value in intent and check that value in tabbed activity. rest is your code. which you need to check

Comment: But it doesn't allow to declare the fragment classes in the manifest file!!

Comment: You can use this way.

Comment: ohh yes i am editting the answer wait. you have written SignupActivity in intent. instead of HomeTaberActivity.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya yes easy way :)

Comment: Yes, That was the problem. Got that working. Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, it's working for me.. Thanks man you save my day!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use

- Create **`STATIC`** method.
- Use INTENT **`putExtra/getIntExtra`** Method. Check **`Vishva Dave's`** Answer.

**1st way**

```
public static ViewPager homeviewPager; //GLOBAL
        public static HomePager adapter; //GLOBAL
        adapter = new HomePager(getSupportFragmentManager(), hometabLayout.getTabCount()); //onCreate section

        public static void _openSIGNIN() // Create this static method
        {
            homeviewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        }

        public static void _openSIGNUP() // Create this static method
        {
            homeviewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        }
```

**HomeTaberActivity**

```
        View.OnClickListener listener_signin_btn = new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, HomeTaberActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    _openSIGNIN();
                }
            };

        View.OnClickListener listener_signup_btn = new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                     Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, HomeTaberActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    _openSIGNUP();
                }
            };
```

Comment: I'm not getting. Can you please explain you answer?
You have mentioned that in HomeTaberActivity I need to write OnClickListener which will not capture the click as the buttons are in the Home Activity

Comment: @AbhishekDS use `INTENT putExtra/getIntExtra`. Send parameter and check and set `setCurrentItem(n)` . n=0/1