# Calling a fragment from another activity, yet both show at the same time?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

So I'm using a button to go from Activity A/Fragment4 to Activity B, and then a button to go from Activity B back Activity A/Fragment4.  I got the forward action working perfectly, and back action sorta works, Activity B and Fragment 4 are on the same screen at the same time now, meaning Activity B was not removed/destroyed.  This is the code from onClick() Fragment4.

```
  public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getContext(), ActivityBActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            getActivity().finish();
            Log.d("BASE_FRAGMENT", "Activity should have been started here");
        }
    });
```

This is the code from my onClick() from Activity B.

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,new Fragment4Fragment());
            transaction.addToBackStack(Fragment4Fragment.class.getName()null);
            transaction.commit();
```

I have tried using finish(); but that just closes the whole app.  And the addToBackStack line does not seem to make a difference.  I have even set the noHistory statement in the Manifest to true, no help.

Comment: So I found my answer on this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903286/how-to-open-a-specific-tabbed-activity-on-button-click)

Answer (score 0):

If your **fragment** is opening in **Activity A**.then back button should do the work.Because pressing back button will open **Activity A** and also the fragment because it is open on Activity A.

If your **Activity A** is not open then first you have to open **Activity A** from **Activity B** and Then open **fragment** form Activity A.

if you add your fragment using **addtobackstack** it means back button first works for fragment just like activities.

If you have any problem jst comment on my answer i will help you then.

Comment: So where is the problem in my code?  Sounds like everything you commented on, I'm doing.  I haven't try doing the "Intent" call.

Comment: @JamesJosephBonds please upload the code of both activities and fragment so i can see

Comment: I've added more code and edited my comments in the original Post.  Hopefully that will explain more.

Comment: @JamesJosephBonds R.id.fragment_container is this present in Activity B layout?

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, yes.

Comment: I found another way to do it @Asad Ali.  I posted the link above.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Nothing to worry @JamesJosephBonds if my answer help you please select this as acepted answer.Thanks!